# how to incorporate multiprocessing in nested loop?

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, multiprocessing

My current code involves reading scan files one by one though a nested for loop, and it takes an embarrassingly long amount of time to do so.

I am hoping to implement multiprocessing in this code so all the scans can be processed faster, but I have no idea how to modify my code efficiently (all of them have resulted in dozens of additional lines and the creation of an obscene amount of global variables).

Here is my code:

```
subjs = session.projects[project].subjects
for s in subjs:
    exps = subjs[s].experiments
        
    for e in exps:
        scans = exps[e].scans
            
        for sc in scans:
            my_file = scans[sc].resources['DICOM'].files[0]
            fname = my_file.data['Name']
            path = my_file.uri

            with my_file.open() as f:
                dicom = pydicom.read_file(f)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!